# Updating pg_catalog.pg_attribute on postgres11 is good?

Tags: postgresql

Does, updating catalog table on postgres11 is good idea as it runs quicker? and I noticed this catelog update valid for future data only not existing ,is this true in all cases?

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_attribute SET attnotnull = TRUE
WHERE attrelid = 'tttt2'::regclass 
AND attname = 'b';
```

Comment: Manually changing the system catalogs is a bad idea. Also any changes will not survive a dump/restore. What is the issue you are trying to solve? Add information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This modification will actually survive dump/restore.

Comment: "*as it runs quicker*" - than what?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I stand corrected. I did not think this through to the part where the table definition is changed and that change is propagated via dump/restore.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying catalogs like that is a bad idea. It can lead to data corruption unless you know exactly what you are doing.

In this special case, I recommend that you create a `NOT VALID` check constraint and use `ALTER TABLE` to validate it later. That avoids a long `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses:

As I don't have dare to update catalog in prod without knowing the impact.

I fallowed with **not valid** (Also suggested by @laurenz ). I will try to spend some time and share catalog impact, once I done some research.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).